# Redux Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to exchange some data between components in my React App and trying to use Redux for the purpose.

I am really looking for simple functionality (storing accesstoken, retrieving accesstoken).

I have one file in folder src/reducers/currenttokenreducer.js:

```
const currentTokenReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SETTOKEN':
            return action.payload
        case 'GETTOKEN':
            return state
        default: return null
    }
}
export default currentTokenReducer;
```

then I have an index.js in src/reducers/:

```
import currentUserReducer from './currentuser.js'
import currentTokenReducer from'./currenttoken.js'
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    currentUserReducer, currentTokenReducer
})
export default allReducers
```

finally in index.js I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import b2cauth from 'react-azure-adb2c';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import jwt from 'jwt-decode'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import allReducers from './reducers';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

const store = createStore(allReducers);
```

and I guess proper encapsulation of App/ with Provider:

```
b2cauth.run(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

In App.js I fire a gettoken function and want to store it both in local state and redux store:

```
componentDidMount (){


   this.gettoken();
}
async gettoken(){
const dispatch = useDispatch();
let apiurl = 'https://get.....azurewebsites.net……'
var token = await Axios.get(apiurl,{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }});
this.setState({accesstoken: token.data});
dispatch (settoken(token.data));
}
```

settoken is defined in src/actions/:

```
export const settoken = (token) => {
    return {
        type: 'SETTOKEN',
        payload: token
    };
};
```

When I deploy it I get:

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See ... for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

And it points to this line in App.js:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like your calling `useDispatch` in Class Component. `useSelector` and `useDispatch` are React Hooks, which only work in function components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't use a hook inside a class component**

Please read the [Rules of Hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

> Call Hooks from React function components.

BTW, you don't need to have a `GETTOKEN` action in your reducer because the token is already stored into the store.

```
const defaultState = {value: null};

const currentTokenReducer = (state = defaultState , action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SETTOKEN':
      return {...state, value: action.payload};
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}

export default currentTokenReducer;
```

Then you don't need to create a internal state inside your component because you will retrieve the token from the store

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'; 
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';

function AppComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const token = useSelector(state => state.token.value);

  useEffect(async () => { 
    const apiurl = 'https://get.....azurewebsites.net……';
    const response = await axios.get(apiurl, ...);
    dispatch({type: 'SETTOKEN', payload: response.data});
  }, []);

  return <div>{token}</div>;
}
```

In this example I used the hooks `useDispatch` and `useSelector`, you can find more information on theses hooks on the [react-redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible that you're trying to use a hook (`useDispatch()`) inside a Class? Because hooks don't work inside classes (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#but-what-is-a-hook).

You can still get `dispatch` from your props with a good old `connect(mapStateToProps)(App)`. (see: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#default-dispatch-as-a-prop)

Comment: You are right. I need to call API in order to be able to display external iframes within App tags and they require authorization bearer (from the API) I thought I need componentDidMount() method and use setState to trigger re-render of the page.

Comment: So it means I cannot use function App() - I had to stick to class. Or I am wrong? What would you suggest to do in such situation?

Comment: @MatnikR I'm not sure I entirely understand your issue here. If you want to dispatch something from your App component, why not just use `connect()(App)` in your code to receive `dispatch` from your props?

Comment: As I am new to React in general, certain concepts are not super clear to me from the start. Definitely the connect () can be used. I'll try to modify it this way and will come back with results - unless you can point me to simple example for this. Everywhere I look it seems to be over engineered from my POV.:-)

Comment: @MatnikR Here's a good start I think: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#default-dispatch-as-a-prop
`useDispatch()` is a simple way to get the `dispatch()` function from a hook, but it's not mandatory at all.